# LinearGradientBrush Background for UINavigationBar

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Can anyone of you tell me how to set a custom background for my `UINavigationBar` ?

It needs to be a LinearGradientBrush. The navgiationbar.TintColor property is of `UIColor` type. Is there a way to set a LinearGradientBrush to the `TintColor` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS5 it is possible to fully customise `UINavigationBar`, and most of the UIKit controls. The easiest way to achieve a colour gradient would probably just be to use a `UIImage` with the gradient drawn in it. You can then set it on the navigation bar using:

```
- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forBarMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006887-CH3-SW16) for more details.